# Writing output in first column of csv

Tags: python, csv

I have sequence of numbers:

> 6577

I would like to see them in the .csv file like this:

```
6  
5  
7
```

I've tried with file writer but it writes all numbers in first row.

sequence is string..

```
s = ['6','5','7','7','6']
item_length = len(s)

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for i in range(item_length):
        file_writer.writerow([x[i] for x in s])
```

Comment: A sequence? Is that a list? A string? An int?

Comment: Please post you code along with question, you will get much more useful feedback that way. Right now `python -c "for d in '6577':print d" > file` solves you problem.

Comment: check out `xlwt` module in python

Comment: `s = '657'` is not the same as `6577`. Which is it? And if there's only one column, why do you need csv?

Comment: Your initial sequence and the expected .csv output and the sequence in the code example are still all different. Is the code meant to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to write each list item as a row, you can try:

```
s = ['6','5','7','7','6']
item_length = len(s)

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for item in s:
        file_writer.writerow(item)
```

Also, with only a single column to write out, this might suffice:

```
s = ['6','5','7','7','6']
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
   test_file.write("\n".join(s) + "\n")
```

Comment: I tried that...But i guess output cannot be writen in columns in .csv

Comment: Glad you found a solution.